# Apache, Tomcat 5 and problem with HTTP basic auth

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, fedora, mod-proxy-ajp, http-basic-authentication

I have setup a Tomcat with a webapp that uses http basic auth in some of its URLs.  There is a  Apache server in front of the Tomcat.

I have setup Apache as a proxy like this (all traffic should go directly to tomcat):

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy_ajp.conf**:

```
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

There is a webapp installed to root of Tomcat (ROOT.war), so I should be able to use http://localhost/ to access my webapp. But it is not working with http basic auth.

The problem is that everything works until I try to access URL that are protected by the HTTP basic auth. URLs without authentication work just fine.

When accessing this url via apache I am getting an error message from Apache. If I access the same URL directly from tomcat, everything works just fine.

I am getting this to Apache error log:

```
[Wed Sep 01 21:34:01 2010] [error] proxy: dialog to [::1]:8009 (localhost) failed
```

access log looks like this:

```
::1 - - [01/Sep/2010:21:34:01 +0300] "GET /protected_path/ HTTP/1.0" 503 360 "-" "w3m/0.5.2"
```

I am using:

- Fedora release 13 (Goddard)
- httpd-2.2.16-1.fc13.x86_64
- tomcat5-5.5.27-7.4.fc12.noarch

The basic auth is implemented in the webapp (not in Apache or Tomcat). The webapp is actually implemented in Scala/Lift, but that shouldn't matter. The auth works if I access the tomcat directly.

Error message that I am getting from Apache. It is curious that the title is *Unauthorized* and not *Internal error*:

> Unauthorized
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>
> Apache/2.2.16 (Fedora) Server at my.server.name.com Port 80

It could be that Apache is seeing a some thing else than **200 OK** response and thinks that it is an error when it actually should pass the received **401 Unauthorized** response directly to browser. If this is the problem, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

How did you configure the basic auth?  If you are using `<Directory>` Directives, try changing to `<Location>` instead. (as the proxied requests don't actually touch an Apache directory..

Edit:
I assume you have: `LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so`

Comment: The basic auth is done entirely by the webapp/servlet, not by apache or tomcat.

Comment: Can you post the httpd.conf or conf.d/ajp.conf file? Do you have anything in the: catalina.out log file in (Tomcat home)/logs

Comment: full conf.d/proxy_ajp.conf is now included

Comment: Oh, just realised that could be an IPv6 error.. are you using it? (::1 indicates localhost right), you could try disabling or removing IPv6.